# Renaming a Collection Using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I realize that a collection can be renamed in MongoDB using

```
db["old_name"].renameCollection("new_name")
```

But is there an equivalent in PyMongo? I tried the following, but it didn't work either.

```
db["old_name"].rename_collection("new_name")
```

Answer (score 14):

According to the [documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.rename), the method is simply named `rename`.

```
rename(new_name, session=None, **kwargs)

     new_name: new name for this collection
     session (optional): a ClientSession
     **kwargs (optional): additional arguments to the rename command may be passed as keyword arguments to this helper method (i.e. dropTarget=True)
```

Comment: yes, so using your example: `db["old_name"].rename("new_name")`

Comment: Link to docs has changed, see my comment further down.

Comment: Docs updated, in future please feel free to just edit the URL.

Answer (score 12):

May be you can use rename in pymongo, just use

```
db.oldname.rename('newname')
```

You can check the link：
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=rename

Comment: [Link to docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html) has changed.

Answer (score 4):

An admin command to [rename a collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/#definition) can be executed in like manner.

```
query = {
    'renameCollection': '<source_namespace>', 
    'to': '<target_namespace>',
}
client.admin.command(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   query = bson.son.SON([
       ('renameCollection', 't1.ccd'),
       ('to', 't2.ccd2'),
   ])
   print(query)
   self.mgclient.admin.command(query)
```

Need to use bson.son.SON, as dict is unordered. Please refer to:

http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/son.html#bson.son.SON
http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html

> Note the order of keys in the command document is significant (the
>   “verb” must come first), so commands which require multiple keys (e.g.
>   findandmodify) should use an instance of SON or a string and kwargs
>   instead of a Python dict.

Comment: ...but in the case of this question, with renameCollection, must the keys be ordered? it seems like perhaps no, a dict is fine...?